# Get Array element from JSON array from mongodb document

Tags: json, mongodb

```
{
"employees" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "XXX",
        "id" : "1",
        "Salary" : [ 
            {
                "Month" : "XXXX",
                "Amount" : "XXXX",
            }, 
            {
                "Month" : "XXXX",
                "Amount" : "XXXX",
            }, 
            {
                "Month" : "XXXX",
                "Amount" : "XXXX",
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "YYY",
        "id" : "2",
        "Salary" : [ 
            {
                "Month" : "YYYY",
                "Amount" : "YYYY",
            }, 
            {
                "Month" : "YYYY",
                "Amount" : "YYYY",
            }, 
            {
                "Month" : "YYYY",
                "Amount" : "YYYY",
            }
        ]
    }
],
}
```

This is sample of json format in mongodb document.
I want to get the result as a one particular element from employees Array that search by name
I tried these methods

```
db.abc.find({"employees.name": "XXX"},{employees: {$elemMatch: {name: "XXX"}}});
```

and

```
db.abc.find({ employees: { $elemMatch: { name: "XXX"} } })
```

none of those won't work. those methods give whole document as a result. can anyone give me a solution on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.abc.find({"employees.name": "XXX"},{"employees.$":1})
```

Comment: Yh. That works. Can you help me to do this with indexing

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: Serch this using indexing

Comment: You have to set indexing first db.abc.ensureIndex({"employees.name" : 1}).